# Speech recognition started and immediately failed with kAFAssistantErrorDomain error 7

Tags: swift, speech-recognition, ios14, xcode12

Some details:
iOS14.0.1
Xcode 12.0.1
iPad Mini gen 5

Our app uses voice as the main user input to navigate the functionalities.

Upon app start, speech recognition works normally. The user would start saying simple English words (Yes/No), and the speech recognizer would start hypothesizing transcription.

However, after a few iterations, the speech recognizer would stop working. Instead of hypothesizing transcription when user speaks, it jumps straight to the `didFinish` task delegate and indicates that speech transcription was unsuccessful with the following error message: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (kAFAssistantErrorDomain error 7.)`

This bug only appeared recently in iOS14 and was not an issue in iOS13. I have googled for this error code/message but could not find much detail. Does any one know what this means/why it is failing?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I am facing something very similar.

Comment: Not really. We're working around this issue by forcing off-line recognition. This has two short-comings: 1. Slower and less accurate, 2. Relatively limited language options. If you only care about recognizing English, this workaround may work well enough.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Are you suggesting that the root cause of this issue is due to online recognition? If yes. do you have access to any developer resource that states this?

Comment: I'm still unsure what the root cause is, and I have no other resources to back it up, but that's what the symptom would suggest.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue now, have you found a fix for this at all? Also, how are you forcing on device recognition, have you ever faced an error where "no models were installed yet?"

Comment: @entropy.maximum have you gotten any luck?

Comment: @MichaelJajou - no luck so far. To force on device recognition, you simply have to set `recognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true`. What's really worrying is the fact that this is erratic and not consistently reproducible.

Comment: Anyone have any luck with this yet? @entropy.maximum

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with the same problem I found out that cancelling to many tasks from `SFSpeechRecognitionRequest`s in a short period of time will produce this behavior. Prefer calling `.finish()` on your `SFSpeechRecognitionTask`s and creating a new one only after `task.state` is completed.